# When is the next significant date on the horizon in the judicial proceedings against Julian Assange?

Tags: united-kingdom, england-and-wales, extradition, current-events

Australian journalist Julian Paul Assange is in remand pending the CPS appeal against his triumph in the extradition proceedings against him for offences under the U.S. espionage act.

When is the next relevant date or time frame within these proceedings? If there are none yet definite on the horizon, are there time limits for how long the indefinite limbo can last?

Answer (score 2):

There is no pending appeal by the Crown Prosecution Service.

[The CPS's appeal was successful, with judgment released on December 10, 2021](https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-59608641). The Supreme Court declined to hear Assange's further appeal of that. [The home secretary then approved Assange's extradition](https://www.theguardian.com/media/2022/jun/17/julian-assange-extradition-to-us-approved-by-priti-patel).

While the question does not ask about this: Assange has now appealed that ultimate extradition approval, but these are new proceedings about a different decision point, not a continuation of the previous appeal, with the hearing expected to be in early 2023.

Comment: Oops, it has gone on so long that it has all just blurred together. Can you expand on why Assange’s appeal is on a different decision point and can you give any references for where to read more about it?